# Error con codigo java en Elastic Searc 6.2

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

Estoy usando la api cliente para java de elastic search e intento hacer una consulta y me marca este error:

> Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch
>   exception [type=parsing_exception, reason=[multi_match] query does not
>   support [auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query]]]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:618)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:594)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:501)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:474)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:391)
>     at
>   com.alejandro.pruebasElasticSearch.App.buscarCatalogo(App.java:111)
>     at com.alejandro.pruebasElasticSearch.App.main(App.java:40)

ESTAS SON LAS DEPENDENCIAS EN MI MAVEN:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Y mi código java algo así:

```
// INSTANCIA CLIENTE REST
RestHighLevelClient cliente = restHighLevelClient();
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indiceYDocumento[0]); 
searchRequest.types(indiceYDocumento[0]);
MultiMatchQueryBuilder query =  QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(busqueda, camposDondeBuscar); 
query.autoGenerateSynonymsPhraseQuery(false);
sourceBuilder.query(query); 
sourceBuilder.size(3);
sourceBuilder.explain(false);
sourceBuilder.indexBoost("concepto", 2);
sourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("_score").order(SortOrder.ASC));
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
```

Comment: Resolviste el problema ??

Comment: Al parecer es por problema de versiones, el cliente java de elastic que estoy usando es el 6.2.3 (el actual) y la versión del elastic search es 6.0.1 ya realice la consulta a uno de la misma versión y funcionó, solo ando esperando que actualicen la versión que se tiene en producción para implementar mi aplicación